# Интервал выполнения цикла по времени

Tags: java, android

Есть цикл:

```
  void someTask() {
      TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

              public void run() {            
                while (parseRep < 2) {
                Document doc = null;
                try {
                   Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/aut.php")
                            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                            .execute();
                   response = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/login.php")
                           .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
                           .data("nick", loginAuth
                                ,"pass", passAuth)
                           .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                           .timeout(30000).execute();


                    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru").cookies(response.cookies()).get();
                    Element blockRega = doc.select("div.foot").first();
                    nav2Reg = blockRega.text();

                    Element usInfo = doc.select("div.nav1").first();
                    usName = usInfo.text();

                    Elements kollMess = doc.select("a[href*=new_mess] div.nav2 font[color=red]");
                    kollNewMess = kollMess.text();
                    System.out.println(kollNewMess);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
               Log.d(LOG_TAG, nav2Reg);


              } //while

              }
        };

      new Timer().schedule(task, 1000, 10000);
  }
```

как мне сделать чтоб повторное выполнение цикла начиналось лишь тогда, когда с момента последнего выполнения прошло 10 секунд?
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

видя метод .start(); сделаю предположение что вы пользуетесь классом Thread. предлагаю использовать TimerTask:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
           //ваш код
        }
};
timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 10000);//первое число - когда он 
//запуститься, второе - через сколько будет повторяться
```

Если только раз это нужно сделать, пользуйтесь Handler-ом:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   //ваш код
};
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
```

И помните - в каком потоке определили Handler с конструктором по умолчанию, в таком он и будет работать. В данном случае в методе run(), в котором работает цикл, будет само то.

Comment: Простите. Не могли бы вы добавить код таймера в мой код(редактировал в вопросе) - у меня почему-то ругается на токен